# How To Remove File After certain period from RackSpace Cloud using Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloud, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I am using 'net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace' to create object and save file to cloud.

I want to delete the newly uploaded file after 30 Days from RackSpace Cloud Automatically.

I have searched a lot about that and found 'X-Delete-After' metadata can be used.
I am not able to get how to implement the same.

I am using following code to create object :

```
CloudFilesProvider cloudFilesProvider = GetCloudFileSytemObject();
cloudFilesProvider.CreateObject(strContainer, fupUploadStream, fileName);
```

Please help me regarding automatic deletion from cloud.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution,
Here is the code for the same

```
CloudFilesProvider cloudFilesProvider = GetCloudFileSytemObject();
Dictionary<string, string> dicMetadata = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dicMetadata.Add("X-Delete-After", "2592000");
cloudFilesProvider.CreateObject(strContainer, fupUploadStream, fileName, headers: dicMetadata);
```

Here '2592000(Seconds)' is equal to 30 Days.

This Code adds header to file 'X-Delete-At' with self calculation of date time of file to be deleted.

Now after the time we want to delete we are able to delete the file content ,
But file it self is not deleted.

I am searching for the same and trying to contact RackSpace Cloud.

Comment: if any one knows how to solve rackspace issue,please answer it

Comment: I found it from 'https://developer.rackspace.com/docs/cloud-files/v1/developer-guide/'. They do delete physically after the date passed and remove content based on date and time.Thanks